# How to pass child object via ajax post request

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

**Edit: A simplified question**

How do I pass the integer selected value from the below options:

```
<select data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Id must be a number." id="CarType_Id" name="CarType.Id">
                <option value="1">V2</option>
                <option value="2">x2</option>
                <option value="3">60-series</option>
            </select>
```

In the format:

```
function saveSummary() {
    var payload = {
        Id: $("input[name=Id]").val(),
        CarType_Id: $("input[name=CarType.Id]").val(),
        SerialNo: $("input[name=SerialNo]").val()
    };
}
```

**Original question**

I have an **ajax call** that works like this:

```
function saveSummary() {
    var payload = {
        Id: $("input[name=Id]").val(),
        CarType: $("input[name=CarType]").val(),
        SerialNo: $("input[name=SerialNo]").val()
    };
    // post to edit action in home controller
    $.ajax({ 
        url: "/Home/Edit", type: "POST", 
        data: JSON.stringify(payload),
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    error: function() {
            alert('Error updating table!')
        },
        success: function (data) {
            alert('Table updated!');
        }
     }
```

This successfully passes the **model** below:

```
public class MyObjectViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CarType { get; set; }
    public string SerialNo { get; set; }
}
```

To this **controller** action:

```
public ActionResult Edit(MyObjectViewModel model) { } // successfully populated model
```

So now let's say I make the `CarType` a class of its own:

```
public class CarType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

So my original model becomes:

```
public class MyObjectViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public CarType CarType { get; set; }  // This is now a type / class
    public string SerialNo { get; set; }
}
```

**How do I then include and pass the `CarType` to the payload?**

I've tried getting just the `Id` for it since the name resolves to `CarType.Id` but the line `CarType: $("input[name=CarType.Id]").val()` doesn't work.

I was thinking I might have to `stringify` the object itself and then append it but I can't seem to get it working.

The HTML looks like this:

```
<form action="/Home/Edit/3572?..." method="post">
    <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="xyz">
                   <dl class="dl-vertical">
                        <dd>
                            <label for="SerialNo">Serial Number</label>:
                        </dd>
                        <dt>
                            megatron_5000
                        </dt>
                    </dl>
                    <dl class="dl-vertical">
                        <dd>
                            <label for="CarType">Car Type</label>:
                        </dd>
                        <dt>
                            <select data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Id must be a number." id="CarType_Id" name="CarType.Id">
                              <option value="1">V2</option>
                              <option value="2">x2</option>
                              <option value="3">60-series</option>
                </select>
                        </dt>
                    </dl>
            <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Id must be a number." data-val-required="The Id field is required." id="Id" name="Id" type="hidden" value="3572">
                    <input type="button" value="Save Changes" id="saveSummaryEditButton" onclick="saveSummary()">
                    <input type="button" value="Cancel Changes" id="cancelSummaryEditButton" onclick="cancelSummary()">
</form>
```

**EDIT**

I tried adding an `int CarTypeId` to receive the value from the `CarType.Id` but it doesn't compile if I use

```
CarType_Id: $("input[name=CarType.Id]").val()
```

Comment: Please share the full HTML. I want to see the CartType form.

Comment: you have changed CarType from a value type to an object in c#? - so you need to do the same in your JavaScript.  you shoud set dataType: 'json',  on your ajax too

Comment: Shobit, I've Added the HTML with some alterations on the actual data. @developer not sure how to do that. I'm quite new to using JS, I'll try and google that.

Comment: your payload is passing a string to CarType:
`var payload = {
        Id: $("input[name=Id]").val(),
        CarType: $("input[name=CarType]").val(),
        SerialNo: $("input[name=SerialNo]").val()
    };`  but should be an object `var payload = {
        Id: $("input[name=Id]").val(),
        CarType: { CarType: $("input[name=CarType]").val(), Id: 99999999 },
        SerialNo: $("input[name=SerialNo]").val()
    };`

Comment: Ah ok, so that's a bit like child objects in `json` - let me try that

Comment: what type of controller is it?  MVC or WEBAPI/2 etc?

Comment: yes - its a child object with key CarType (same as your C#), with two properties: CarType &Id (same as your C#) - so model binding can match

Comment: Web.MVC - not having any luck. Can't even get it to pass the selected value from control `name=CarType.Id` back to a new integer I created, never mind the model itself. Doesn't compile if `name` has a `.` suffix :s

Comment: I ended up plucking value by `#id` because `name=something.Id` didn't work